# Changing style in Awesome-CV

Tags: cv, awesome-cv

I'm using awesome cv template. I want to edit some style here. You can see from the picture that university name is the first item. But I want to make it the last item but also it should have the same style as before *i.e* the location color. Basically I can just swap the text but I want the same style here. This is the code of this section:

```
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
 \cventry
{B.Sc in Computer Science and Engineering}
{University of ABC}
{Poland}
{Jan. 2014 - Jan. 2018}
{
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item {GPA - 4.46}
  \end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine what `\cventry` does. The original definition is found in [`awesome-cv.cls`](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls).

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{awesome-cv} % https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV

% Redefine an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#3}                                            % #2 removed
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {                     & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\    % \entrytitlestyle{#2} removed
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
    \ifempty{#2}{}{\\ \entrytitlestyle{#2}}                 % Added
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
 \cventry
{B.Sc in Computer Science and Engineering}
{University of ABC}
{Poland}
{Jan. 2014 - Jan. 2018}
{
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item {CGPA - 3.46}
  \end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

[image: cv entry]